# How to bind gridview to another grid view?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, gridview

I am using `2 gridview` in my project, i binded the employee on one grid  and i want to show the orders of each employee on the second. i am stuck at filtering the other employees, when i hit the show orders button it shows me all the orders, how can i point at the right index(the employee selected)? .

My code:

```
private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        using (NorthWindDataContext db = new NorthWindDataContext())
        {

            var query =
                from d in db.Employees
                select new
        {
            d.FirstName
        };
            dataGridView1.DataSource = query;
        }

}  

private void displayOrdersToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        using (NorthWindDataContext db = new NorthWindDataContext())
        {

            var query =
                from o in db.Orders
                select new
                {
                    o.ShipName <----problem  here :(
                };
            dataGridView2.DataSource = query;

        }
}
```

Please help

Thanks

Comment: what is the error exception?

Answer (score 2):

Use [GridView.SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedvalue.aspx) Property.

You need to write something similar to:

```
private void displayOrdersToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (NorthWindDataContext db = new NorthWindDataContext())
    {

        var query =
            from o in db.Orders.
                Where(item => item.ID == dataGridView1.SelectedValue)
            select new
            {
                o.ShipName <----problem  here :(
            };
        dataGridView2.DataSource = query;

    }
}
```

Comment: i cant see the SelectedValue prop, i have select row,select cell,Selected Columns and some othere..